# range names not in name manager

Tags: vba, excel

Running VBA code allowed me to detect that applying a filter in a sheet creates a range name that does NOT appear in the name manager (the range name either just associates to the headers or the whole table). Is there any way of knowing why this happens and/or a way of preventing it? Is it just an Excel glitch?

the part of the vba code that causes the error I tried to run was the following:

```
For Each Rng In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Set Rng2 = Range(Rng)
    If Not Intersect(Rng2, Range(rng1.Offset(1, 0), rng1.End(xlDown)).EntireRow) Is Nothing Then ActiveWorkbook.Names(Rng.Name).Delete
Next Rng
```

When I was debugging, I noticed that my Rng (which is a name object, by the way) points towards a range I never created (and I know this because the sheet that it's in has no other range names and I never put any in it)
I used this vba code to verify that the name existed in this sheet:

```
Sub test()

Dim Rng As Name

For Each Rng In Sheets("WindHail Zone 2").Names
    'ActiveWorkbook.Names(Rng.Name).Delete
    MsgBox Rng
Next Rng

End Sub
```

I removed the comment block from the first line of the for loop to the second line to delete it. I removed the filter on that tab and reput it on, only to come to the same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: That... Just doesn't happen. Any way we can reproduce that? What kind of filter? What VBA code? Some more info is needed.

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details: including code snippets, what you've tried so far, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so clear to me what your're trying to achieve but as long as "hidden" names and range intersection are involved you must take into account what follows:

- filtering does create hidden "names"

  but all of them ends with the string "_FilterDatabase"
- range intersection wold return an error if applied to ranges not belonging to the same sheet

so here what you should try

```
For Each Rng In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Set rng2 = Range(Rng)
    If rng2.Parent.Name = rng1.Parent.Name And InStr(Rng.Name, "_FilterDatabase") = 0 Then 'the first check is for ranges belonging to the same worksheet and the second is for rng2 not deriving from any filtering
        ' now you can safely "Intersect"
        If Not Intersect(rng2, Range(rng1.Offset(1, 0), rng1.End(xlDown)).EntireRow) Is Nothing Then ActiveWorkbook.Names(Rng.Name).Delete
    End If
Next Rng
```